# Flask-Dramatiq-Callback must be an Actor

Tags: flask, dramatiq

When working with `dramatiq 1.9.0` (`flask-dramatiq 0.6.0`) I'm unable to call `on_success`- or `on_failure`-callbacks. The [official dramatiq-documentation](https://dramatiq.io/cookbook.html) states callbacks can be used like this:

```
@dramatiq.actor
def taskFailed(message_data, exception_data):
    print("Task failed")

@dramatiq.actor
def taskSucceeded(message_data, result):
    print("Success")

dramatiqTask.send_with_options(args=(1, 2, 3), on_success=taskSucceeded, on_failure=taskFailed)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR - on_failure value must be an Actor
```

In `.../site-packages/dramatiq/actor.py` there is

```
def message_with_options(self, *, args=None, kwargs=None, **options):
    for name in ["on_failure", "on_success"]:
        callback = options.get(name)
        print(str(type(callback))) # Returns "<class 'flask_dramatiq.LazyActor'>"
        if isinstance(callback, Actor):
            options[name] = callback.actor_name

        elif not isinstance(callback, (type(None), str)):
            raise TypeError(name + " value must be an Actor")
```

which shows that the callback isn't from the type `Actor` but flask-dramatiqs `LazyActor`.

If I import the original package with `import dramatiq as _dramatiq` and change the decorator to `_dramatiq.actor`, nothing happens at all. The task won't start.

How do I define callbacks in `flask-dramatiq`?

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you find any fix for flask_dramtiq. The documentation is not good for dramtiq

Comment: @GiriAnnamalaiM Unfortunately, I did not. We're still using celery right now.

Comment: Yes. I'm moving back to celery. Its matured right now. May be I will try Dramtiq they updated their documentation and examples.